# Cross-browser JS-only image-resizing prior to upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, resize

What solutions are there for resizing images before uploading with ajax? No flash- silverlight - plugin-solutions whatsoever please.

jQuery-solutions highly preferred.

I am working on a solution with canvas but there seems to be a lack of image quality and browser support for older IEs.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [FAQ])

Comment: as you can see here, yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679299/canvas-drawimage-fails/15679851?noredirect=1#comment22260121_15679851 but no luck so far and no support for older browsers

Comment: Can you say what is the purpose of resizing the image. That could help me give you better idea .Please explain your requirement.

Comment: Yes sure... it's a "mobile-first" application where users can post things, also upload images. For saving bandwith, I'd like to be able to pre-resize the images on the client-side. It's not a big problem if it does not work on older browsers IF there is a proper fallback (i.e. just uploading the whole pictures). The form just contains one simple input type file, no drag & drop required, no multiupload. Form submission through ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post may help you: [Is there any way to resize a image before saving to Web SQL in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867647/is-there-any-way-to-resize-a-image-before-saving-to-web-sql-in-html5)

The base64 data from toDataURL can be sent to your server and then be processed as you intend it to be.

Comment: this looks very good, I just need a proper fallback for not-supported browsers. Seems doable...

Answer (score 0):

@Raphael Jager: use imgresize option in javascript to resize, Here by setting a property say height to a fixed value you can resize the image for coerresponding width for the same aspect ratio.. check gd image library for resizing

Answer (score -2):

Javascript cannot read files locally, on client's computer, for security purposes. Therefore I'm afraid there is no solution.

Comment: with HTML5 File that's not true I think?

Comment: @RaphaelJeger - well yes, but older IEs don't support HTML5.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, sorry about that. Therefore this eventually perfectly seems to become possible ^^" I could just head you to [jQuery image manipulation tools then](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/image-manipulation/). Good luck !

Comment: And indeed, as Spudley says, you have no (little?) hope of reading local images in deprecated browsers.

Comment: thank you blint and Spudley - I'll look into that. For older browsers, I just need a workaround, even if that means non-resized images get uploaded. Of course the images will still be checked server-side and resized if necessary... But I don't want to transfer more data than necessary for mobile users, and they have modern browsers :)